# What does Felyne Weakener do?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

Going to the canteen to eat before embarking on a quest is standard procedure, and different combinations of ingredients give you different buffs and skills. Most of them are self-explanatory and usually buff yourself in some way, but there's one that the game doesn't explain very well: Felyne Weakener.

The ingame description is:

> Increases the likelihood of large monsters encountered in Quests being weak.

But it doesn't go into any further detail.

What does "weak" mean in this context? What is the "increased likelihood"? If multiple players activate Felyne Weakener, does it increase the chance further?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When spawning a monster (at mission start or everytime a monster spawns in multimonster missions) the game will set a monsters health there are 5 posible state:

- very weak
- weak
- standard health
- durable
- very durable

this skill doesn't let monsters with the durable or very durable trait spawn.

If more than a player has the skill it only increases the likehood of the skill activating and only activating it once per monster not per player.

Some quest are unafected by this skill because the monster health for that specific quest is fixed.

Comment: in case you are curious this is about mh3 , mh3p and mh3u but still valid since the introduction of this cooking skill, take into account that it seems to be glitched for mh3u
http://www.capcom-unity.com/monster_hunter/go/thread/view/146585/30358161/felyne-weakener

Comment: That's some interesting mechanical knowledge.  I hadn't realized that's how Weakener works.