# How does Felyne Weakener work in MHW/Iceborne?

Tags: monster-hunter-world, monster-hunter-world-iceborne

I found and read [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209403/what-does-felyne-weakener-do), yet I am wondering a few things.

1. Is the basic functionality (5 different health states) still the same?
2. If I have the skill active for an quest, can still durable/very durable monsters spawn?
3. Does the 1 HP bug exist in MHW/Iceborne?
4. Has anything else changed with this skill in Iceborne?

From the linked question, the following sentence confuses me very much:

> If more than a player has the skill it only increases the likehood of the skill activating and only activating it once per monster not per player.

Could someone explain what exactly is meant here?

Answer (score 2):

In Monster Hunter each quest (or investigation) has set modifiers for health pool, part break defense, spawn location, and a few other variables. Essentially there is very weak, weak, normal, durable, and very durable. Last I read it works the same in MHW/Iceborne as it always has. It gives you a chance to remove durable and very durable type monsters, and you will have a better chance at a 'weaker' monster with lower hp/part defense modifiers.

The simple answer - you have a chance of the monster having less health. This does not stack with other players, and there is always a chance for it to do nothing. Like "Felyne Insurance" (the first faint doesn't count against the quest limit) - "Felyne Weakener" will be activated for that instance. Additional players with the same food perk will not add another free faint or make the chance of a weaker monster higher - it's a quest perk and not a player perk.

Comment: You say that if multiple players have Felyne Weakener, then that makes no difference to only 1 player having it. This contradicts with `If more than a player has the skill it only increases the likehood of the skill activating`. So what is it? Do you have sources?